# How to use ACTION_SEND intent from a Dialog which itself has been called from a service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

My app creates chat heads with the help of a service using System Alert Dialog Box. Now I have some images inside that dialog and want to share them using an intent.

But I get the error that:

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from
>   outside of an Activity  context requires the 
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   flag. Is this really what you want?

How to fix this ?

Code Im using to share the image is:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {

            //Toast.makeText(cont,"hola",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Uri uri = imageAdapter.getUri(position);
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            sharingIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, ""));

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it correct myself.
The correct code is:

```
Uri uri = uri_ad;

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    sharingIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    Intent ni = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"");
    ni.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    getmContext().startActivity(ni);
```